# How do we use LoggingRetryPolicy and FallthroughRetryPolicy with DriverConfigLoader In Java driver v4?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Our application implements retry policies such as FallthroughRetryPolicy and LoggingRetryPolicy using driver cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar.To support keyspace metadata for DSE6.8,we are upgrading the datastax driver version to java-driver-core-4.13.0.

For policies DefaultRetryPolicy,ConsistencyDowngradingRetryPolicy we can programatically use its  class name in DriverConfigLoader.But,how can we implement FallthroughRetryPolicy and LoggingRetryPolicies,as these policies aren't available in java-driver-core-4.13.0.?Trying to use driverconfigloader as below

```
DriverConfigLoader loader =
                DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder().withClass(DefaultDriverOption.RETRY_POLICY,DefaultRetryPolicy.class).build();
```

LoggingRetryPolicy in our application is as below:

```
public static RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy(String retryPolicyStr, boolean isLogingPolicy) {
        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = null;
        if (isLogingPolicy) {
            retryPolicy = new LoggingRetryPolicy(retryPolicyDataConvert(retryPolicyStr));
        } else {
            retryPolicy = retryPolicyDataConvert(retryPolicyStr);
        }
        
        return retryPolicy;
    }
    
    private static RetryPolicy retryPolicyDataConvert(String retryPolicyStr) {
        if (CassandraConstants.CASSANDRACONNECTION_RETRYPOLICY_DEFAULT.equals(retryPolicyStr)) {
            return DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE;
        } else if (CassandraConstants.CASSANDRACONNECTION_RETRYPOLICY_DOWNGRADING.equals(retryPolicyStr)) {
            return DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE;
        } else if (CassandraConstants.CASSANDRACONNECTION_RETRYPOLICY_FALLTHROUGH.equals(retryPolicyStr)) {
            return FallthroughRetryPolicy.INSTANCE;
        } 
        
        return null;
    }
Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
builder.withRetryPolicy(CassandraPolicyDataTypeConvertUtil.getRetryPolicy(connectionInfo.getRetryPolicy(), connectionInfo.isLoggingRetryPolicy()));
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The `FallthroughRetryPolicy` and `LoggingRetryPolicy` do not exist in version 4.x of the Cassandra Java driver so you will not be able to use them.

Java driver v4 only comes with two built-in retry policies:

1. `DefaultRetryPolicy`
2. `ConsistencyDowngradingRetryPolicy` (do NOT use)

We do not recommend using `ConsistencyDowngradingRetryPolicy`. If you decide to use it, make sure you fully comprehend the consequences. In all cases, the correct retry policy to use is `DefaultRetryPolicy` unless you have a very edge case and want to implement your own retry policy.

For more info, see [Retries in Java driver v4](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/retries/). Cheers!